# pyradio find the file station.csv

Tags: python, ubuntu

I install [pyradio](https://github.com/coderholic/pyradio/tree/master) to listen radio on my terminal. On the [guidelines](https://github.com/coderholic/pyradio/tree/master) this line `pyradio --stations STATIONS`supposed to show me the path where my stations.csv is installed but I didn't find nothing. I want to know where this file is to add or delete radio stations.

```
g@ubuntu:~/Music/radio_online/pyradio$ pyradio --stations STATIONS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyradio", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyradio==0.5.2', 'console_scripts', 'pyradio')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyradio/main.py", line 40, in shell
    with open(args.stations, 'r') as cfgfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'STATIONS'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of stations.csv:

```
# Find lots more stations at http://www.iheard.com
Slay Radio (C64 Remix), http://www.slayradio.org/tune_in.php/128kbps/listen.m3u  
DefCon Hack Radio, http://sfstream1.somafm.com:6200/  
SomaFM SF Radio, http://mp2.somafm.com:2040/  
SomaFM SF Radio 2, http://somafm.com/m3u/sf1033.m3u/  
SomaFM SF Radio 3, http://somafm.com/sf1033.pls  
Romania Actualitati, http://stream2.srr.ro:8000/    
Radio Zu, http://stream.radiozu.ro:8020  
Radio XNet: Manele Xnet, http://www.radioxnet.ro/asculta.m3u
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
--stations STATIONS, -s STATIONS
     Path on stations csv file
```

Means you can optionally provide a valid cvs file with stations.

Comment: ok thanks z4r! but how do I know the format (The columns) of the csv file that I will create.

Answer (score 1):

The `--stations` option allows you to specify a .csv file with the radio stations. It's not there to show you the actual one.

Looking at the pyradio's main.py:

```
DEFAULT_FILE = ''
for p in [path.join(getenv('HOME', '~'), '.pyradio', 'stations.csv'),
          path.join(getenv('HOME', '~'), '.pyradio'),
          path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'stations.csv')]:
    if path.exists(p) and path.isfile(p):
        DEFAULT_FILE = p
        break
```

It seams that the stations.csv is by default in the same directory where pyradio is installed. Additionally you can create stations.csv in your home directory in a subdirectory called `.pyradio` or (if I understand well) put the entries in a file called `.pyradio` in your home directory.

Comment: Thks! Andrei for the info!